# Images served through PHP script display fine in browsers but not in email clients

Tags: php, wordpress, html-email

I have a site that allows users to browse images and purchase prints of those images. The site runs on Wordpress and the ecommerce side has been written as a plugin.

I want to store the images outside of the web root directory, and so have created a script in the plugin called show-image.php which looks like this:

```
<?php

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

function show_images($content) {

    // Clean the buffer, we're not sending anything but the image
    ob_end_clean();

    global $wpdb;

    //get the ids passed in the url
    $w    = get_query_var("gwpw",false);
    $i    = get_query_var("gwpi",false);

    // if either passed var is not an integer, set them to false
    if (!filter_var($w, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array('min_range' => 1)) || !filter_var($i, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array('min_range' => 1)))
    {
        $w   = false;
        $i   = false;
    }

    $w_table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'table1';
    $i_table_name   = $wpdb->prefix . 'table2';

    $wrow = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $w_table_name WHERE wid = %d",$w));
    $irow   = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $i_table_name WHERE itemid = %d AND wid = %d",$i,$w));

    $i_path = realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../') . '/' . $wpdb->prefix . 'images/' . $w . '/' . $irow->filename;

    if (!$w || !$i || $w == null || $i == null || !file_exists($i_path) || !is_file($i_path))
    {
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
        exit;
    }

    // get the image details, send them in the header, then send the file and exit

    $info       = getimagesize($i_path);
    $fs         = filesize($i_path);

    header ("Content-Type: {$info['mime']}\n");
    header ("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"$irow->filename\"\n");
    header ("Content-Length: $fs\n");

    readfile($i_path);

    exit;
}
?>
```

And in functions.php for the plugin I have:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'gwp_ec_content_filter' );
add_filter('query_vars', 'gwp_ec_filter_queryvars' );

function gwp_ec_content_filter ($content)
{
    if (get_query_var('gwpw',false) && get_query_var('gwpi',false))
    {
        $content = '';
        $content = show_images($content);
    }

    return $content;
}

function gwp_ec_filter_queryvars( $qvars )
{
$qvars[] = 'gwpw';
$qvars[] = 'gwpi';
return $qvars;
}
```

This all works perfectly in a browser, I can browse to www.mysite.co.uk/?gwpw=1&gwpi=1 and I'm served the image I should be. I've checked it is not the browser cacheing the image, I am truly being served the image.

However, when I include this as a src attribute for an image tag in an HTML email, Apple Mail on iOS and OSX won't display the image. I can view the source of the email, copy and paste the url for the image out of the message source and into a browser and it works fine.

I'm thinking it must be something wrong with how I'm serving the image in show-image.php, as if I point the src at an image inside the web root directory e.g. `www.mysite.co.uk/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/image.jpg`, then the email clients display the image fine.

If anyone has any ideas they would be gratefully received!

Comment: Normally modern email clients won't fetch external resources by default, for security/privacy reasons.  There's usually an option when viewing the email to change this, but that's going to differ by email client.  In general it's preferred to embed the content as resources in the email itself, so the message is entirely self-contained.

Comment: ^ that - though embedding the image obviously increases the filesize so it's not necessarily a good idea on mass mailings (e.g. newsletters). Could also be that Apple thinks it's likely to be a tracking pixel (because of the URL paramters) and is blocking it; you could try using `mod_rewrite` to create a "fake" URL for the image, containing the parameters, e.g. *www.example.com/images/pic-gwpw-1-gwpi-1.jpg* and parse it to fetch */?gwgw=1&gwpi=1*

Comment: It's not that, the email client is displaying the image when linked direct, just not when using the url with parameters. I thought embedding the image should be avoided because many web based clients strip them out, i.e. gmail, yahoo etc.. There are static images in the email linked externally e.g. social media icons etc which display fine.

Comment: @CD001 that's an interesting idea with `mod_rewrite`. I'll give that a try. Thanks